# Lambdaexpression of Linq-query in a variable

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda, expression

How can I define a lambdaexpression that I want to use in a linq query as a variable?

For example when sorting a generic list by different properties of the listitems:

```
 IList<SampleClass> list = new List<SampleClass>();

 // Populate list
 ...

 list.OrderBy(sampleclass => sampleclass.property1);
 list.OrderBy(sampleclass => sampleclass.property2);
```

I would like to define the lambda expression (sampleclass => sampleclass.property1) in a variable and call:

```
// ??? define expression in a variable ???
Expression expression = sampleclass => sampleclass.property1;

// Sort list by variable expression
list.OrderBy(expression);
```

Thanks in advance
Tobi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one of `Func` overloads ([`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) precisely):

```
Func<SampleClass, PropertyType> expr = sampleclass => sampleclass.property1;
list.OrderBy(expr);
```

`PropertyType` is the type of variable stored as `property1` in your `SampleClass`. If it was for example `string`, you would use `Func<SampleClass, string>`.

Answer (score 2):

Define a `Func<TSampleClass, TPropertyType>` as follows:

```
  List<SampleClass> list = new List<SampleClass>();   
  Func<SampleClass, int> expr = (c) => c.SomeProperty;
  _HungerLevel = level;


  class SampleClass
  {
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: this does not work: 
"Cannot assign lambda-expression to an implicity-typed local variable"

Comment: @Tobias Did you use the var keyword when declaring the Func?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Func<SampleClass, int> f = sampleClass => sampleClass.Property1;
list.OrderBy(f);
```

This presumes the type of Property1 is int.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost already done it.

The parameter is any function taking an item from the sequence and giving its key as a result (the key on which the ordering will be done). A lambda expression is just a variety of such a function.

These notations are possible :

```
list.OrderBy(sampleclass => sampleclass.property1);
```

or

```
Func<SampleClass,string> getKey = sampleclass => sampleclass.property1;
list.OrderBy(getKey);
```

or

```
string GetKey(SampleClass sampleclass)
{
    return sampleclass.property1;
}

list.OrderBy(GetKey);
```

(I supposed here that `property1` was a string but it's of course not a requirement !)

Answer (score 0):

Just like other people said, you can use `Func<T, TResult>` to store delegate to your function.

If you want to use something else than Linq-To-Objects, then you should enclose this in Expression too. Something like `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking purely about LINQ to Objects, there's no need for `Expression`s here because the argument to `Enumerable.OrderBy` is a `Func` delegate:

```
var list = new List<SampleClass> ();

Func<SampleClass, PropertyType1) orderSelector1 = (obj => obj.Property1); // parentheses for clarity
var sequence1 = list.OrderBy (orderSelector1);

Func<SampleClass, PropertyType2) orderSelector1 = (obj => obj.Property2);
var sequence2 = list.OrderBy (orderSelector2);
```

If you want to assign multiple times, you can make `Func` return `object`:

```
var list = new List<SampleClass> ();
Func<SampleClass, object> orderSelector;

orderSelector = (obj => obj.Property1);
var sequence1 = list.OrderBy (orderSelector);

orderSelector = (obj => obj.Property2);
var sequence2 = list.OrderBy (orderSelector);
```

If you truly want **dynamic** property selection, i.e. calling `OrderBy` with a property specified by a `string`, you would need `Expression`s. There are plenty of examples in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby) that allow you to do something like:

```
var list = new List<SampleClass> ();
var sequence1 = list.OrderBy ("Property1");
var sequence2 = list.OrderBy ("Property2");
```