# Emebeded Statement can not be a declaration or labled stateme

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I am trying to store a linq express in a variable, But it gives me this compile time error

> Emebeded Statement can not be a declaration or labled stateme

I found how to assign a linq expression to a variable from this question of stackoverflow
[Lambdaexpression of Linq-query in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120807/lambdaexpression-of-linq-query-in-a-variable)

But When i try to implement it, I get the below error , 
Can someone help me ?

The code I tried

```
 if (dtpFrom.DateTime != null) 
           Func<BAL.Receipt , DateTime? > expr = receipt => receipt.Date ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that snippet of code isn't valid C#.  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2496644/2779530) other StackOverflow answer explains why.  To summarize that answer, the C# specification states that the body of an if statement must be an *embedded-statement*, which does not include statements that are variable declarations.

To get your code to stop causing that error, you can try just throwing brackets around the if statement body:

```
if (dtpFrom.DateTime != null) 
{
    Func<BAL.Receipt , DateTime? > expr = receipt => receipt.Date ;
}
```

Although this won't do much of anything, since you're just storing that lambda in a temporary variable of type Func<,> which only has scope in the if statement.  You'll either have to use it within the if state body or store it somewhere else.